# How to load only a specific attribute instead of all attributes with load()

Tags: magento-1.9

How to load only a specific attribute instead of loading all attributes in magento 1.9? I'm using the code below, but it loads all the information and I just need the product ID.

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $_customOptions['simple_sku']);
```

Comment: Did you try with addAttributeToSelect("*")?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code,

```
$sku = 'some-sku';
$productId = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getIdBySku($sku);
```

Thanks & Regards,

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return entity id from sku then magento have already function

**getIdBySku($sku)** for it.

Ex.

```
$sku = 'some-sku';
$productId = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getIdBySku($sku);
if($productId){
echo "your product id" . $productId;   
}
```

You can also get single column value with **getColumnvalues**. may be it would return with array format.

Ex.

```
$productCollection->getColumnValues('entity_id');
```

Magento also provide **reset** for select only specific field.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->getSelect()->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS)->columns(array('entity_id'));
```